# Jumper and switch settings for 286 Suntac mainboard

Tags: identify-this-computer, 80286

I have a 286 mainboard here, which is I think very similar to this [one here at stason.org](http://stason.org/TULARC/pc/motherboards/U/UNIDENTIFIED-286-SUNTAC-286-12.html). Below is an overview image, and a [link to a album](https://m.imgur.com/a/zuqvm) with details.

However there are still some discrepancies, so I wonder if someone has an actual manual for this device. I can't find any useful make or model, apart from that it was used by Peacock Computers, but they were just a PC manufacturer in the day, and the T90 label on the upper ISA slot. There are no FCC IDs or anything else identifying the supplier.

[image: 80286 Suntac mainboard]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice piece! Those days such boards were designed for specific chassis, with additional keys and LEDs like Turbo. Here're some manuals:

[HT-286](http://minuszerodegrees.net/manuals/Suntac/Suntac%20HT-286.pdf) - the one similar you found, but it is not yours.

This [Super-286](http://toastytech.com/manuals/Magitronic%20B233%20Manual.pdf) seems the one you need though.

Comment: It is the exact board! Very nice detail: One can use 421000 DRAM ICs to add up to 4 MiB of RAM. I did not think this was possible on boards with DIP sockets.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answer, stason.org also has this board as unidentified:

http://stason.org/TULARC/pc/motherboards/U/UNIDENTIFIED-286-JS-128A.html

[image]